# HTTP Status 405 - on glassfish server

Tags: java, servlets, netbeans

I'm using netbeans IDE
This is the servlet code

```
public class CheckBox23 extends HttpServlet {

    public void doGet(HttpServletResponse rs, HttpServletRequest rq) throws IOException, ServletException {
        rs.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter posh = rs.getWriter();
        posh.println(docType+"<html>"+"<body>"
                    +"<ul>"
                        +"<li><b>Math Flag: </b>"+rq.getParameter("maths") + "\n"+"</li>"
                        +"<li><b>Math Flag: </b>"+rq.getParameter("chem") + "\n"+"</li>"
                    +"<ul>"
                    +"</body>"+"</html>");
    }

    public void doPost(HttpServletResponse rs, HttpServletRequest rq) throws IOException, ServletException {
        doGet(rq,rs);
    }
}
```

This is html code:

```
<form action="CheckBox23" method="POST" target="_blank">
    <input type="checkbox" name="maths" /> Maths
    <input type="checkbox" name="chem" />
    Chemistry
    <input type="submit" value="Select Subject" />
</form>
```

I'm getting `HTTP Status 405 - HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL
type Status report`whenever I'm submitting the form

Comment: please paste the web.xml file..

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"><servlet><servlet-name>CheckBox23</servlet-name><servlet-class>CheckBox23</servlet-class></servlet><servlet-mapping><servlet-name>CheckBox23</servlet-name><url-pattern>/CheckBox23</url-pattern></servlet-mapping><session-config><session-timeout>30</session-timeout></session-config></web-app>

Comment: try to change `<servlet-class>CheckBox</servlet-class>` to `<servlet-class>CheckBox23</servlet-class>`. Also, try to change url pattern. Your form's action attribute should match to url pattern

Comment: sry it was `CheckBox23` actually I pasted it from another project..

Comment: @Logan96 As shown in Shokhrukh's answer, you should always include the **@Override** annotation when overriding doGet() and doPost(). If you had done that in your original code you would have received a helpful compiler error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    //handle request
}
```

You should change method params order